# Italics within plotmath expression cannot be rendered bold in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

Based on previous posts I worked out how to use `expression()` to get a string within a string italicised while the rest of the string remains un-italicised. The problem is that `element_text(face = "bold")` does not work on strings inside `expression()`.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width)) + 
       geom_histogram(bins = 10) + 
       ylab(expression(paste("% of group ", italic("n")))) + 
       xlab("Actual Treatment") + 
       theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold"),
             axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

To get around this I wrapped the `expression()` in `bold()` like so

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width)) + 
       geom_histogram(bins = 10) + 
       ylab(expression(bold(paste("% of group ", italic("n"))))) + 
       xlab("Actual Treatment") + 
       theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

But alas the italicised *n* remains unbolded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expression(bold("% of group ")*bolditalic("n"))
```

Comment: Thank you. What does the `*` do?

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width)) + 
geom_histogram(bins = 10) + 
labs(y=expression(bold(paste("% of group ", bolditalic("n"))),
x="Actual Treatment"))+
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.